# Attach a file to gmail directly from Sharepoint (no outlook client - no onedrive synch)

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, attachments

is there a way to attach a file straight (not download and upload) from Sharepoint site using a gmail email and with no third party app?
For many reason I can't use the following method:

- synch sharepoint with one
- use outlook client or using the office 365 outlook email

I found a sort of solution, but then the sharepoint website remains open from the gmail account also if I log out from everything and enter with a different gmail address, so I'm not so happy with this.
My way was, when attaching a file, putting the website address in the name field, log in and then it shows all the folders.

These attachment are for external and must be a copy of the file. They are sent on random occasion, so it's not an automated process (so i think I can't use flow).

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid that is beyond SharePoint’s ability.

It would be possible to [attach files directly from SharePoint Online](https://sharepointmaven.com/7-ways-to-attach-sharepoint-documents-to-an-email/), using Power Automate for example, as long as you have access to these Online services.

The problem is, your requirement is to send emails via a Gmail account, which would be identified as an external account. External users do not have access to Microsoft Flow because they cannot be licensed, and we cannot send an email on another user’s behalf.